# How can I add icons login in Magento Homepage header?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, checkout

How can I add icons social and  login in Magento 1.9 Homepage header?

Answer (score 0):

`app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml`

```
<default> 
    <reference name="header">
        <block type="core/template" name="social-icons" template="page/html/social-icons.phtml" />
    </reference> 
<default>
```

`app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/page/html/header.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('social-icons') ?>
```

`app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/page/html/social-icons.phtml`

```
<!-- social network content goes here -->

<div class="social-network-icons">
    ...
</div>

<!-- Login content goes here -->
<div class="login-logout">
    <?php if ( ! Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() ): ?>
            <span><a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl("").'customer/account/login'; ?>"><?php echo $this->__("Login"); ?></a></span>
    <?php else : ?>
            <span><a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl("").'customer/account/logout'; ?>"><?php echo $this->__("Logout"); ?></a></span>
    <?php endif; ?>    
    ?>
```